# Azure Bot Composer framework - Dialog Loop

Tags: azure, botframework, artificial-intelligence, azure-bot-service

I am learning bot composer framework and I have difficulty in reading user input

I fall into a loop with prompt for text and user input

loop -

[image: loop]

prompt for text and user input settings -

[image: prompt for text and user input dialog settings]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial-create-weather-bot#prompt-a-user-for-input) to the doc to prompt a user for the input.